# Automate mailto process

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

How can I automate the mailto process, instead of a new compose window pop up in one of the mail clients is it possible to have the email send in the background, thus not having the user to click send.

Overall I want to receive a email from one of the customers that contains there choice "Approved" or "Rejected" and have them simply press on either button and the email be sent automatically and then maybe after they have clicked on the button have it redirect them to a page stating what decision they made etc.

If it's not possible to automatically send a email from there inbox without there permission so to speak as it'll be automated is there a way to capture or get there email along with there choice and have that send to orders@macwearembroideryclothing.com

Approve & Reject button code:

```
<a href="mailto:orders@macwearembroideryclothing.com?subject=Review&body=Rejected" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">

<a href="mailto:orders@macwearembroideryclothing.com?subject=Review&body=Approved" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
```

Gmail Client:

[HTML Email Before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLqMo.png)

[After approve button has been pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0dYa.png)

Comment: Sure. Use [mail()](http://php.net/mail) or (preferred) a library such as phpmailer.

Comment: I remember you posting a question similar to this not too long ago and you deleted it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have access to any information about (or be able to send through) your users email account without their co-operation - so that approach is pretty much written off.

I think the key thing here is that **your server** needs to do the work, and send an email to you. How you do this will depend on which server technology you use - but most will be able to handle it. As mentioned in the comments php has various ways of sending emails.

You could ask the user their email address, name etc... and then include this in the email that your server sends to you.

A good start would be finding an example of a 'contact us' form that works on your server, and removing all the fields you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

> If it's not possible to automatically send a email from there inbox without there permission

It isn't. If it was possible it would be both an invasion of privacy and a huge risk of turning visitors into spam relays.

> is there a way to capture or get there email

No. See above: Invasion of privacy.